# Using Apache2 Worder MPM with Moodle

Tags: apache-2.2, mpm-worker, mpm-prefork, moodle

Is Moodle (I am using Moodle 2.5.2) compatible with Apache2 "Worker MPM" (in contrast to "Prefork MPM").

If it is indeed compatible, has has anyone tried both and is able to say which performs better and if so what is the performance difference between the two?

Thanks!